# Javascript : Ajax and Show/Hide Div

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use Ajax to request some information for my web page, and pops up a "Please Wait" window while the Ajax is running.

This is working fine in Mozilla and Chrome, but the "Please Wait" window does not show up in IE.

Here is my code :

```
function openWaitMessage()
{
   var wid = 300;
   var hgt = 200;
   var left = 0;
   var top = 0;

var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}

var scrOfX = 0, scrOfY = 0;
if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
    //Netscape compliant
    scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
    scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
    //DOM compliant
    scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
    //IE6 standards compliant mode
    scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
}

left = scrOfX + (myWidth - wid)/2;
top =  scrOfY + (myHeight - hgt)/2;


var div = document.getElementById("pleaseWait");
div.style.display = '';
div.style.visibility = 'visible';
div.style.left = left;
div.style.top = top;

 } // openWaitMessage()

   function getInformation { 
       openWaitMessage();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // create a new ListRequest object and add the 'category' parameter //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var listRequest = new ListRequest("lotatt-request");

    /////////////////////////////////////
    // create a new AjaxRequest object //
    /////////////////////////////////////
    var ajaxRequest = new AjaxRequest("/MyProject/services");

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    // send the list request to the server //
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    sendListRequest(ajaxRequest,listRequest,fillLotAtt,ajaxError); 
   }
```

HTML :

```
   <div id="pleaseWait" style=" display: none; visibility: hidden;  position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:300px; height:200px; z-Index:999;">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
        <tr class="dialogHeaderCell" >
            <td>
                Please Wait...
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <img src="please_wait.gif" alt="Loading...Please wait.">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

  <input type="button" name="DisplayInfo" class="secondary_button" value="Display Information " onClick="getInformation ()"/>
```

Please help, Thanks ahead

Comment: `//IE 4 compatible` good god, is that necessary?

Comment: Maybe it's offscreen? Did you inspect the left and top properties of the div with IE dev tools?

Comment: How can I do that? Can you guide me? I have IE Dev Tools installed but have no idea how to do use it

Comment: So alert `left` and `top` right before the end of the function.

Comment: Is this old legacy code? Can you use jQuery instead?

Comment: Also please create a reproducible version using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). That way it would be easier to help you with your problem.

Comment: @Behrang Saeedzadeh, yes, I can use JQuery, but I am not an expert on JQuery, where can I start with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sprenna, as you have mentioned you also have the option of using jQuery. If you want some kind of an in-depth read, then have a look at [these three free jQuery books](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/05/3-free-e-books-on-jquery.php).

If you want a shorter introduction, have a look at [this list of jQuery tutorials](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html).

However, in short, using jQuery you can use this code to show/hide an HTML element:

```
$("#pleaseWait").show();
// or
$("#pleaseWait").hide();
```

`#` is an ID selector. So `#foo` selects an element that its ID is is `foo`.

Then you can use the jQuery [`offset` function](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2) to position elements relative to the document.

Finally you can use jQuery [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2) and [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2) functions to set the size of your desired element(s).

I also recommend you to read [Pro JavaScript Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597273) by the creator of jQuery. It improves your JavaScript knowledge and skills significantly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is not appending the CSS unit when setting `left` and `top` programatically. Try this:

```
div.style.left = left + 'px';
div.style.top = top + 'px';
```

I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQ8JM/) so we can play with your code.